# Best way to store text data for streaming

Tags: c#, streaming

I am implementing a cache that would be storing contents of text files in a web server. When an incoming request comes, the contents of the file would be streamed from the cache.

What is a good way to store contents of the files in cache nodes - should I use a string or a byte array? Please discuss the pros and cons of each option. And is there any other better option?

Answer (score 0):

They are text files, so it makes sense to store the contents in a text format.

Therefore, I would suggest storing the file contents as strings, each of which you can populate with a call to `File.ReadAllText()`.

This way, accessing the cache will give the same result as if the file were being loaded as text.

The most sensible collection for the cache itself is probably something like `ConcurrentDictionary<string,string>`, which you can key off the file name (or other unique identifier for the file you're loading).

A typical file cache implementation could be like this:

```
public class FileCache
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string,string> fileContentsCache 
        = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();

    public string ReadAllText(string filePath)
    {
        return fileContentsCache.GetOrAdd(filePath, File.ReadAllText);
    }
}
```

Usage would be:

```
var cache = new FileCache();
var fileText = FileCache.ReadAllText(requestedFilePath);
```

The cache would pull the text out (if it's already in the cache), or load the file and return the string (if it's not).

Note that if you want 1 global file cache for your entire application, you can make the FileCache class (and all its members) static.